# Ebooks in advanced calculus

Tags: calculus, soft-question

This semester I'm taking advanced calculus and in the sources list, the lecturer recommends on "An introduction to analysis-by w. wade" and "Advanced calculus by Edwards". Both of them cost around 100 dollards in amazon.Paron if the question is too soft or too rude but suppose I don't want to pay 200$ for a semester, is there any cheap/free alternative (maybe mailing the printout and asking permission for my private use?).

Answer (score 0):

1 Advanced Calculus by Loomis and Sternberg is available for free download from Schlomo Sternberg's web site, BUT is written at an abstract level, probably only suitable for good math majors.

2 I think the 1912 Advanced Calculus by E B Wilson is available on google books